Adding Text to the White Space of a Cropped Image
Consider the code:
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{pspicture}

% Paddings.
\PreviewBorder=1cm\relax


\newsavebox\IBox
\savebox\IBox{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}}

\def\N{15}% columns
\def\M{15}% rows

\psset
{
   xunit=\dimexpr\wd\IBox/\N\relax,
   yunit=\dimexpr\ht\IBox/\M\relax
}


\begin{document}
% First page for navigation
    \begin{pspicture}(\N,\M)
        \rput[bl](0,0){\usebox\IBox}
        \psgrid[style=gridstyle] 
    \end{pspicture}
    

% Cropping coordinates
    \def\Left{3}
    \def\Bottom{5}
    \def\Right{12}
    \def\Top{10}
    \begin{pspicture}(\Left,\Bottom)(\Right,\Top)
        \begin{psclip}{\psframe[linestyle=none](\Left,\Bottom)(\Right,\Top)}
            \rput[bl](0,0){\usebox\IBox}
        \end{psclip}
   \end{pspicture}
\end{document}

which produces:

QUESTION: How may I add some text (say, "added text") in the white space beneath the word "Image" in the second pspicture. If possible, I do not want to increase the amount of white space in the cropped image.
I am using Xelatex to compile.
Thank you.

I've never used pspicture, but can't you just use another \rput?

Yes, that is one of the things I used in the past for pspicture environments, but this time I couldn't produce text in the cropped image. In any case, the answer below seems to do the trick. Thank you for your suggestion.

Well, it wasn't much of a suggestion. ;)

\begin{pspicture}(\Left,\Bottom)(\Right,\Top)
\begin{psclip}{\psframe[linestyle=none](\Left,\Bottom)(\Right,\Top)}
    \rput[bl](0,0){\usebox\IBox}
\end{psclip}
\rput(!\Right\space\Left\space add 2 div \Bottom\space 1 sub){\Large A nice Image}
\end{pspicture}

If you want the text to be a part of the picture environment, then use
 \begin{pspicture}(\Left,\dimexpr\Bottom cm-2.5cm\relax)(\Right,\Top)



Thank you for this answer. I had previously tried using \rput  but couldn't get any text to appear. Thanks again.
